# Woocommerce how to get product category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories, woocommerce-theming

I want to create a drop down list for categories in php in a page built in code. I could create a shortcode for it successfully but since shortcode is not friendly with html, I decided not to pursue that route. So without any scripts or jquery, I'm attempting to add php code into a div

```
<select class="store-search-input form-control" name="dokan_seller_search" value="<?php

                $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
                $orderby      = 'name';  
                $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
                $title        = '';  
                $empty        = 0;

                $args = array(
                        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                        'orderby'      => $orderby,
                        'show_count'   => $show_count,
                        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                        'title_li'     => $title,
                        'hide_empty'   => $empty
                );
                $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
                foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
                    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
                        $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
                        echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

                        $args2 = array(
                                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                                'child_of'     => 0,
                                'parent'       => $category_id,
                                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                                'title_li'     => $title,
                                'hide_empty'   => $empty
                        );
                        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
                        if($sub_cats) {
                            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                                echo  $sub_category->name ;
                            }   
                        }
                    }       
                }
        ?>" >       
        </select>
```

and this happened:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Update thanks to Alex's help:
I don't have enough points to add the image directly yet:

[image]

```
<input type="select" class="store-search-input form-control" name="dokan_seller_search" value="<?php
            $args = array(
                'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
                'orderby'      => 'name',
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'hide_empty'   => false
            );
            $all_categories = get_categories( $args );

            esc_html('<select class="store-search-input form-control" name="dokan_seller_search">');

            foreach($all_categories as $parent){

                if ($parent->category_parent == 0) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$parent->name.'"><a href="'. get_term_link($parent->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $parent->name .'</option>';
                }

                $args2 = array(
                        'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
                        'child_of'     => $parent->term_id,
                        'parent'       => $parent->term_id,
                        'hide_empty'   => 'false'
                );
                $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
                if($sub_cats) {
                    foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                        echo  $sub_category->name;
                    }   
                }

            }
            esc_html('</select>');
            
    ?>">
```

The result I'm expecting is a

[image]

Comment: Hey, just a couple of advices on how to improve your question to increase the chance of getting help here: 1. add screenshot directly to the post (not everyone may want to click links); 2. maybe add a description of what you were expecting to happen vs what actually happened; 3. To help anyone debug your code just by looking at it, it would really be helpful if you could provide the RAW HTML which was generated by it (NOT the screenshot of render).

Comment: You have in effect created a <Select> without any options. So nothing appears even if the code produces results.

Comment: @IvanR thanks for the advice! Will improve on it :)

Comment: Please do not add images in question. Read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a little dirty for a . You would be much better off using a dropdown triggered by javascript so you can better control the DOM in the dropdown. A select should really only be used when you need to submit data to the server.

UPDATE: This is tested and working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //First, some js to trigger the window to relocate when you click an option

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        //When the select is triggered
        jQuery('#category-links').on('click', function(){

            //Get the URL from the selected option
            var url = jQuery(this).val();
        
            //Navigate to the url
            window.location.replace(url);

        })

    })
</script>


<?php
//Get the parent terms
$parents = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent' => 0
]);

//Start the dom for the select
echo '<select id="category-links">';
    echo '<optgroup>';

        //The parent option
        echo '<option value="'.get_term_link($term->term_id).'">'. $term->name .'</option>';

            //Check for children, if there are we'll add them here
            $children = get_term_children($term->term_id, 'product_cat');
            if (!empty($children)) {
                foreach ($children as $child) { 
                    $childterm = get_term_by('id', $child, 'product_cat');
                    echo '<option value="'.get_term_link($childterm->term_id).'">'. $childterm->name .'</option>';
                }
            }

        echo '</optgroup>';

    }

echo '<select>';
```

Comment: Hey Alex! Thanks for your response and I agree that there are better methods to do it. Would you have any other suggestions to do it better? I've also tested the code you've provided and it didn't work so I've made some adjustments to it but the outcome isn't complete

Comment: I'll put this into a wp install and test it now.

Comment: @booak you should find the above suitable. If you take a look at jQuerys dropdown toggle library you should be able to adapt the code above to work well with that. But, the above works anyway.

Comment: I've added your code into the <select> tag and the script at the bottom of the footer but the outcome looks like this: usku.com.au/store-listing any thoughts? How did you implement your code while testing to make it work?

Comment: Then you have added it wrong. The code contains a select tag so you dont need to add it inside the select. Replace the select you already have with the code above. All i get when i look at your URL is a 404.

Comment: The url was privated. Should be working now! I've added your code outside the select tag and that's the result

Comment: There is a @font-face error in your code somewhere. Inspect the select with your dev tools and open the first optgroup element. Fix this and it should work.

Comment: still wasn't able to fix it :(  I've found a workaround at the moment, but if this could be resolved, that'd be amazing

Comment: It wont work as expected because there is a font face error in your code. You need to fix that so the select can carry on working. The solution above does work as Ive had it working

Comment: I can't seem to find the @font-face error in the css code. Could you point it out to me on where you found it?

Comment: From your browser, inspect the select element in your dev tools and expand optgroup inside it. You will see the error.